# When preparing to upgrade Django is there an upgrade check?

Tags: django, upgrade

Is there an easy way it identify potential issues when upgrading Django? What features have been deprecated? What 3rd party libraries have compatibility issues?

I know there are release notes with some of this information. I'm upgrading several sites and several different version at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that this is a great case for writing some tests in your application if you don't already have them.

A strong test suite allows you to do the following:

1. Spin up your django app
2. Run tests to confirm they pass
3. Upgrade your django version or 3rd party modules
4. Run tests again to confirm they pass
5. Repeat

On the grand scale of most django projects, so many things change/deprecate/improve that it's impossible to keep a list of them. Your tests can always serve as a source of truth in functionality.